# How do I install the GnuPG PHP extension?

Tags: snow-leopard, php

I'm having trouble installing a PHP native extension: GnuPG. Here's what I've tried so far.

First:

```
sudo port install gpgme
sudo pecl install gnupg
```

Output from the second command ends like so:

```
checking for gnupg support... yes, shared
checking for gnupg files in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the gpgme distribution
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/gnupg/configure' failed
```

So, I tried installing manually, guessing at some values based on output of `port contents gpgme` and `port contents gnupg`...

```
pecl download gnupg
phpize
./configure --with-gnupg=/opt/local/include --with-libdir=/opt/local/lib
```

Alas, no luck. This ends like so:

```
checking for gnupg support... yes, shared
checking for gpgme_check_version in -lgpgme... no
configure: error: wrong gpgme lib version or lib not found
```

I then tried augmenting CFLAGS like so:

```
CFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib" ./configure --with-gnupg=/opt/local/include
```

This returns a nonzero exit code, but then `make` fails. Here's the end of that output:

```
/bin/sh /tmp/gnupg-1.3.2/libtool --mode=link cc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/gnupg-1.3.2/include -I/tmp/gnupg-1.3.2/main -I/tmp/gnupg-1.3.2 -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/include/php -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/include/php/main -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/include/php/TSRM -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/include/php/Zend -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/include/php/ext -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/opt/local/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -L/opt/local/lib   -o gnupg.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath /tmp/gnupg-1.3.2/modules  gnupg.lo gnupg_keylistiterator.lo -Wl,-rpath,/opt/local/include/lib -L/opt/local/include/lib -lgpgme
cc ${wl}-flat_namespace ${wl}-undefined ${wl}suppress -o .libs/gnupg.so -bundle  .libs/gnupg.o .libs/gnupg_keylistiterator.o  -L/opt/local/lib -L/opt/local/include/lib /opt/local/lib/libgpgme.dylib /opt/local/lib/libassuan.dylib /opt/local/lib/libgpg-error.dylib /opt/local/lib/libintl.dylib /opt/local/lib/libiconv.dylib  -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/local/include/lib
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/include/lib'
ld: duplicate symbol _gnupg_keylistiterator_class_entry in .libs/gnupg_keylistiterator.o and .libs/gnupg.o for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [gnupg.la] Error 1
```

I'm suspicious that my `--with-gnupg` arg somehow messed up linking, because I see `-L/opt/local/include/lib` in the output of that failed `make` run.

That's where I'm stuck. Feels like I'm trying way too hard or just going down the wrong path.

I'm using Snow Leopard (v10.6.8). The PHP command-line program I'm using came with [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/) 2.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

See http://measure9.varkel.net/2013/10/building-gnupg-for-php-5-5-on-osx/ (a lengthy text explaining how to patch & build gnupg from source)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Answers which consist of nothing but a link may be removed.